# best way to catch exception in visual studio c++ debug mode only happen when running from IDE

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception

i have application that is Multi-threading , with stacks . and objects there is also static global members involved ( i know .. not good ) 
i getting exception thrown from different place each time. can't catch it . 
what is the best strategy to catch it .

getting :

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0135f2a7 in myapp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.
```

**UPDATE**
i notice that when i compile in release mode and running it outside the IDE , its working just fine , how can it be?

Comment: You could make a dedicated exception-handling thread for exceptions that cannot be dealt with locally. Everyone else should package their exceptions in `std::exception_ptr`s and pass them on to the handler thread.

Comment: can you please point me to link /example

Comment: Well you have to catch exceptions in threads (otherwise you application is going to terminate). So put a catch block where the thread starts. You should also have a catch everything in main() (though you may just rethrow in main (but it forces the stack to unwind correctly).

Comment: As regards your update... multithreading bugs are seldom straightforward and deterministic. It is safer to assume that your software is at fault, and that the fact that it runs fine on one machine in one configuration is just luck.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that what you are trying to do is to resolve a specific issue rather than have a general run-time exception handling mechanism?

Under the "Debug" menu of VS2010 and 2012 is an option marked "Exceptions...". You can request that the VS debugger break into the application when an exception is thrown; this should give you some insight into exactly what is going wrong and where.